# File in c language

Tags: c, file, fgetc

I need help about my code, I got some works, and it is one of the assignments.

---

suppose an encrypted file was created using the encoding/decoding scheme.

Each letter is substituted by some other letter according to a given mapping as shown below.

```
char * letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

char * enc = "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe";
```

For example, every `a` becomes a `k` when encoding a text, and every `k` becomes an `a` when decoding.

You will write a program, encode or decode a File, and then encodes or decodes the File using the mapping above.

Capital letters are mapped the same way as the lower case letters above, but remain capitalized.

For example, every 'A' becomes 'K' when encoding a file, and every 'K' becomes an 'A' when decoding.

Numbers and other characters are not encoded and remain the same.

Write a program to read a file and encode the file to an encrypted file.
And write a program to get an encrypted file and decode to original file. 
Your program should prompt the user to enter an input file name and an output file name.

Ask for input file name/ output file name (encrypted file). The encrypt using above encode/decode.

Ask for encrypted file and decoded to original input file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
char letters[]={"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
char enlet[]={"kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropweKNGCADSXBVFHJTIUMYLZQROPWE"};
char infile[20];
char outfile[20];
char ch;
int i;

FILE *org, * enc, *dec;

printf("Enter file name (***.txt) : ");
gets(infile);

printf("Enter saving file name (***.txt) : ");
gets(outfile);

org = fopen(infile,"r");
enc = fopen(outfile,"w+");

while((ch=fgetc(org))!=EOF)
{
    for(i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
        if(letters[i]==ch)
        {
            ch=enlet[i];
        }
    }           
    fputc(ch,enc);
}
fclose(org);
fclose(enc);

return 0;
}
```

this code is working but letters doesn't change correctly.
If there are "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" in my original file,
then, it happens "felcadlpbrfhjeiqmwleqropwe" in encoded file.

I expected it would be "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe"
I don't know what are the errors in my code.

Comment: What have you done to try and debug it? Did you run the program in a debugger? Did you put printf debug statements in to try and understand where things may be going wrong? Also, what do you mean by "code is working"? If it is not doing what it is supposed to then it cannot be said to be "working". Or do you mean it works with some inputs but not others?

Comment: Notes: 1) `char ch;` --> `int ch;` to properly distinguish all characters read from `EOF`. 2) Use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`.  3) check results of `fopen()`.

Comment: Please consistently indent the code:  suggest indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}.   This includes the braces at the beginning and end of each function.

Comment: file names can be greater than 19 characters long.  'gets()' will allow the user to overrun the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.   'chux' suggested using fgets() to input the file names.  That would still limit the file names to 19 characters, but would avoid the buffer overrun problem.  Suggest using 'readline()'  then trimming the trailing newline char sequence to get the file name.  Note: you will also have to trim the 'newline' char sequence if using fgets()

Comment: When calling fopen() for the output file, just use "w" for the mode parameter, as  this program is not also reading from the output file.

Comment: it is poor programming practice to use 'magic' numbers within the code. for this line: 'for(i=0;i<52;i++)' suggest using: 'for(i=0; i < strlen(letters); i++)'   Note: inserting a space between parameters makes the code much more readable.

Comment: once a character is 'encrypted' the 'for' loop needs to be immediately exited, so no character gets 'un-encrypted'  'break' works well for exiting the 'for' loop immediately

Comment: the posted code only encrypts the file.  so certain variables, like 'FILE *dec;' is not used.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The above unused variable will output a warning about the unused variable.   Since the posted code only encrypts, 1) suggest two executables, one for encryption and one for decryption.  2) Start the code by displaying a statement that this executable encrypts the file.  3) suggest updating the prompts for the file names to indicate 'clear text file name'  and 'encrypted file name'  because current prompts are vague.

Comment: the character strings letter[] and enlet[] never change. IMO: they are cluttering the stack.  suggest moving them to 'file scope' space and prepending the 'static' modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Your if block should read:

```
if ( letters[i]==ch )
{
    ch = enlet[i];
    break;
}
```

so that `ch` is not replaced twice.  I.e., the moment you know the substitution for that input file position, break, and move on.

Comment: Right!! Thank you So much

Answer (score 2):

Inside this loop, you overwrite ch after it has been replaced.

```
while((ch=fgetc(org))!=EOF)
{
    for(i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
        if(letters[i]==ch)
        {
            ch=enlet[i];
        }
    }           
    fputc(ch,enc);
}
```

You could do one of two things:

1. Instead of assigning ch=enlet[i] just do the fputch(enlet[i])

or

2. Do break the loop as soon as you found a match

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the for() loop and just use:

```
if( org && enc ) 
  while( (ch=fgetc(org))!=EOF)
  {
    char *p = strchr( letters, ch );
    fputc( (p)?enlet[p-letters]:ch, enc );
  }
```

Also, you really should declare ch as an int to compare it to EOF.  And gets() is a buffer overflow waiting to happen and crash your program / provide a security exploit hook (use fgets() and remember to parse off the trailing newlines).  And you never check to see if org and enc aren't NULL (files opened successfully)